# Confused about how an ARM32 processor distinguishes between a register and immediate instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, instructions, machine-code, instruction-set

I am looking at various instructions for an ARM32 processor, and am confused about how the processor is able to distinguish between an instruction that operates on registers and an instruction that operates with an immediate value. For example, in the ARM32, for the MOV instruction, for the immediate and register version, to me, it seems possible that you could have instructions that are exactly the same in machine code. If this is the case, how does the processor "know the difference"?

Comment: You might like to try assembling both versions and looking at the machine code.  I think you'll find they're not the same.  A careful read of the instruction specifications ought to confirm this.

Comment: If you're still unsure, could you post a specific example of two instructions that you think would encode the same, what you think the corresponding machine code would be, and your logic as to why you think so?  They surely don't, but someone could probably help you spot the flaw in your logic.

Comment: IIUC, ARM 32-bit machine code (non-thumb) uses a "flexible 2nd operand" for most opcodes, which can be a register, shifted register, or an immediate.  This difference is encoded somehow; check the manual for details.  And no, of course 2 different instructions can't have the same encoding.  The same bit-pattern always decodes the same way.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you are thinking thumb2 extensions to thumb which are forumerly undefined instructions that turn into two half word instructions.  the first 16 bits show it is thumb2 the whole 32 bits are the instruction with the rest of the encoding in both parts in cases

Comment: all instructions are unique as documented.

Comment: @old_timer: I was mostly guessing; the ARM documentation that turns up when I google an instruction usually doesn't list actual encodings, and I don't usually look at actual ARM machine code.  So I was guessing that "flexible second operand" was a real thing in machine code, not just documentation.  But according to @ Frant's links in the now-deleted answer, I think it's actually a different opcode for the immediate forms of instructions.  But either way, I wasn't thinking of the mechanism for signalling a 32-bit Thumb2 instruction.

Comment: ARM is fixed length 32, thumb is fixed length 16 and thumb2 is two 16s no more no less.  for cortex-m3's on up they support thumb2 so from a processors perspective it is variable length but the options are 16 or 32 total bits specific instructions are one length or another and can be determined by the first 16, so if you look at it from that angle some processors support a thumb mode where there is an optional second operand.

Comment: I assume with ARM32 in the question that means the armv7 and older full sized arm instructions  the Ax encodings (A1, A2, ...) in the latter ARM ARM docs.  (vs thumb Tx (T1, T2, ...) encodings).  But ARM32 could mean "not aarch64".

Comment: AFAIK, there is a magic block on each cpu, instruction decoder:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/instruction-decoder

Answer (score 1):

Are these the two you are confused about?

```
xxxx0011101x0000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx mov immediate
xxxx0001101x0000xxxx00000000xxxx mov register
```

bit 25 is different.

Please read the ARM documentation.

Comment: if you read higher up in the documentation you will see that xxxx00Z  where 27:26 are 00 that is data processing Z = 0 is data processing register and Z = 1 is data processing immediate.  so xxxx000 is data procesing register, the next bits are documented to indicate and,or, subtract, test, mov, etc. and then you get into registers and immediates and other stuff, the top four being the condition field of course.